# On the Homology of Posets

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Is there a homology theory of posets which computes topological invariants (e.g., number of $k$-faces, etc.) of the associated Hasse diagrams (viewed as simplicial/cellular/singular complexes) as perhaps ranks of homology groups or values of Hilbert polynomials of nice rings (e.g., Stanley-Risner, Cohen-Macaulay, etc.)?

For example, the Hasse diagram of the Boolean lattice $B_{n}$ has $2^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}$ $k$-faces and therefore euler characteristic $\sum_k (-1)^k f_k = 1$. Is there a homology theory which relates the Boolean lattice to a contractible space? (Note the solid $n$-cube is homotopy equivalent to the $n$-ball.)

Answer (score 3):

Given a poset, $P$, one can form an associated simplicial complex called the order complex $S(P)$, by letting the underlying set of $P$ be the vertices, and the faces are the totally ordered subsets. Applying standard algebraic topology invariants, such as homology, to the complex $S(P)$ we can obtain invariants of $P$ in some sense.

If we let $P = 2^X$ for some set $X$ with the inclusion partial order, we see that there is a maximal element $X \in P$, and thus the geometric realization of $S(P)$ contracts to the vertex $X$.

Comment: What does the order complex say about the Hasse Diagram viewed as a polyhedral complex? If one is contractible, does it imply it is so for the other?

Answer (score 1):

You may look at [[Poset Topology]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset_topology) and the related lecture notes by Michelle L. Wachs.